# RegWrite to HKLM isnt working. Any ideas?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a key and a value which will reside in the HKEY_Local_Machine folder.

Every time I try and run the below code I get the error "Invalid Root in registry key".

```
Dim WshShell, bKey
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\", 1, "REG_BINARY"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\MindReader", "Goocher!", "REG_SZ"

bKey = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\")
WScript.Echo WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\MindReader")
```

The above will work if I want to create within the HKCU folder.

Does anyone know why I get an error when I try and change the location from HKCU to HKLM?

Or could someone give a brief example to writing a reg value to the HKLM?

Comment: Permissions is usually the culprit, try running the script with elevated permissions.

Comment: The problem comes that you must run it with admin rights to write on `HKLM`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

'Your actual code goes here
Dim WshShell, bKey
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\", 1, "REG_BINARY"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\MindReader", "Goocher!", "REG_SZ"

bKey = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\")
WScript.Echo WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\ACME\FortuneTeller\MindReader")
```

Answer (score 1):

As a Windows User the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry hive belongs to you, but `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` doesn't and depending on the version of Windows you are running will usually require elevated privileges to read/write to.

Make sure you start your script with elevated privileges, which can be done by starting an elevated privilege Command Prompt then executing your script using `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`.